# PHP a number with 0 before

Tags: php, string, numbers, return

I woudlike to return a number with php with 0 before like

> 0001 or 00006.

I found 2-3 solutions on internet to write a 0005 string with php's method :

```
sprintf("%02d", $num);
str_pad($month, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

but this return string, not number.

Do you know if exist a way to get a **00001 number** ?

Comment: You have to deal with the string. 00001 will **always** be converted to 1

Comment: Numbers don't start with `0` except for the number `0`.

Comment: thanks you. This is not convenient..

Comment: Note that if you try to use a number with a leading `0`, PHP will treat it as an octal number (base 8).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it not convenient? You presumably want the variable as a number so that you can do mathematical operations on it, in which case `00001` and `1` would work exactly the same (since they're the same number). Then when you display it, you need it as a string, and so you apply your formatting and add the leading zeroes. None of this is unique to PHP, it's just how type systems work.

Comment: thanks for tips ! :) 
My bad, i think number in PHP :01 !== 1 ! == 00001
but it 's look logic if you consider in mathematic, 01 = 1 = 00000001..